# How to close an UWP app with custom URL scheme?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, windows

I have created a Sample App for Windows (UWP) and registered an URL scheme

**myscheme**

It has a WebView with source as my custom URL like

```
http://192.168.1.25:8080/dummywebsite.html
```

To open App I am using win+r and type **myscheme://hello** and app gets open

I am handling close app with this URL
**myscheme://close**

Problem is when I call `window.location = "myscheme://close";`
its asking *Do you want to switch app* and then when I click Yes it is closing app. Why is it asking to switch app when I already in that App

How can I close app directly from external javascript or remove that confirmation to switch app

MainPage.xaml

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" >
        <WebView x:Name="WebView1" Source="http//:192.168.1.25:8080/dummywebsite.html" ScriptNotify="WebView1_ScriptNotify" />
    </Grid>
```

App.xaml.cs (close Logic)

```
protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        // calls when qlicket url is fired 
        if (args.Kind == ActivationKind.Protocol)
        {
            ProtocolActivatedEventArgs eventArgs = args as ProtocolActivatedEventArgs;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("App Activated");
           
            /// Close App
            if (eventArgs.Uri.AbsoluteUri.Contains("close"))
            {
                global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Application.Current.Exit();
            }
        }
    }
```

Edit 1:

As suggested by Martin Zikmund I tried doing same but javascript throws error.

I think AppCommunicator is not getting registered.

Following below link might help to make it work

> The object passed into AddWebAllowedObject must be imported from a
> Windows Runtime component that is separate from the app assembly. This
> is necessary for the AllowForWeb attribute to be property identified
> by the WebView security subsystem. If you use a class from your app
> project, AddWebAllowedObject does not work.

Refer [WebAllowedObject](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/netframework/en-US/6edeaec1-faa4-4c2c-9f2e-c772cbc72c7f/cweballowedobjects-how-to-publish-properties-to-javascript?forum=wpdevelop) for more detail

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the `WebView` control runs an embedded version of `Edge`, which is "technically" not the same application and that causes the popup.

A better solution would be to invoke C# code directly from JS. You can do that using Web allowed object. This is an instance of a special Windows Runtime class, that will be allowed into JS and you will be able to communicate using the instance. Because First you need to create a new **Windows Runtime Component project**. There you define a class with the `[AllowForWeb]` attribute, which will then be callable from JS:

```
[AllowForWeb] 
public sealed class AppCommunicator
{
    public void CloseApp()
    {
        Application.Current.Exit();
    }
}
```

Now add a reference to this new project from your main UWP app project and then you need to inject an instance of the class to the webpage:

```
private void MainWebView_NavigationStarting(WebView sender, 
                WebViewNavigationStartingEventArgs args)
{ 
   sender.AddWebAllowedObject("AppCommunicator", new AppCommunicator());
}
```

And now you can just call methods on the object from JS:

```
AppCommunicator.CloseApp();
```

### Script notify

There is an alternative way of notifying C# code from JS and that is `ScriptNotify`, but that is supported only for HTTPS websites. For more info see [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/web-view).

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but adding AppCommunicator in same Solution didnt work. AppCommunicator is not available in Javascript . As per this link It has to be in seperate project.  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/netframework/en-US/6edeaec1-faa4-4c2c-9f2e-c772cbc72c7f/cweballowedobjects-how-to-publish-properties-to-javascript?forum=wpdevelop

Comment: Hi, I have updated my answer with the info on Windows Runtime Component

Answer (score 0):

I have added WebView1_ScriptNotify method which is invoked whenever window.external.notify(param); is called from UI

```
// Add in MainPage.xaml.cs
void WebView1_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Value != null && e.Value.Contains("close"))
    {
        global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Application.Current.Exit(); // closing App if close is passed as arg
    }
    else
    {
        /// Other stuffs
    }
}
```

WebView1_ScriptNotify is defined in WebView as

```
ScriptNotify="WebView1_ScriptNotify"
```

**Note**: window.external.notify will be accessable in javascript only if you add ContentURIs by

Solution => Package.appxmanifest => ContentURIs Tab

Sample Uri:

```
http://192.168.0.105:8080
```